# Get the cell address using excel cell formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

My date range starting point can vary at any column, but the row is always fixed at row 2.
For example, my current date range covers from A2:AB2
    col A | col B | col C | ...
    blank | 1-Jan | 2-Jan | ...

I need to achieve the following:
If I enter a date(eg. 2-Jan) at cell A5, cell B5 will display the cell address ($C$2) which contains the date (2-Jan).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Would cell B5 need to be blank, or could it contain a formula that would only display if a date was entered in cell A5? Could the date you enter in cell A5 be anywhere in your data, that is, in column AA5, or E15, for examole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula in cell B5 should do the job:

```
  =IFERROR(ADDRESS(2,MATCH(A5,$A2:$AB2,0)),"")
```

Note that row 2 is hard-coded in the formula by the 2 in the address function.

Comment: I guess I must not be understandng the question. Your question says that your data are always fixed at row 2, as my formula is. The match function compares the date in A5, if any, with that data row and, using your data example, returns the address "$C$2". What am I missing?

Comment: solved. =ADDRESS(2, SUMPRODUCT( ($A2:$AB2=A5) * (COLUMN($A2:$AB2)) ) )

Comment: ADDRESS(row number, column number). But using match formula, it will return the "row number" and not the column number. That's why it always return address $B$2. Thanks for the inspiration.